# OOPs concept in hello world class

Tags: java, oop

This question was asked to me in an interview where the interviewer asked me to write a simple Hello World program in java. This is the code that I wrote.

```
class Greeting
{ 
     public static void main(String[] args)
     { 
          System.out.print("Hello World!");
     }
}
```

Then I was asked which of the OOPs concepts this code implements. I think it uses inheritance as every java class by default extends Object class. But would like to know if other OOPs concept are being used here and if yes then how?

Comment: If you created another class and had your main class instantiate an object and then called a method containing the message then that would be a better example of OOP. While it is true this class is inherited from java's object class it is kind of a weak example because every class is a child of the Java Object class.

Comment: Personally, I don't think this question is specific enough. I would try and get more out of the interviewer, However, if I was in your situation I'd say the answer would be Polymorphism as you could pass in different arguments to the print method and different behaviours would happen.

Comment: Typical interview question: no bearing on real-world programming, just a test to see who's swallowed a book on OOP terminology.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Why would the method behave in different ways?

Comment: @arkascha the `print` method is overloaded in The [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) class.

Comment: `class`, `public`, `static`, `System.out.print` (note the chaining) are all things you could use as a hook, I guess.

Comment: @arkascha Okay, obviously, in this case, the method would simply print out the result regardless of whether you pass in a number, string, character etc but according to the question at hand, Polymorphism would suit the question as for example System.out.print("1"+1); is different behaviour to System.out.print(1+1);

Comment: Should of just said "none".  Maybe they were looking for someone who doesn't needlessly complicate things all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Visibility modifiers are not OOP. The only OOP thing about this is that it is Java and that you have created a class structure with a static method.

You are technically correct that all objects that do not explicitly extend anything — implicitly extend the Object class.

```java
class Greeting                              // class
{ 
     public static void main(String[] args) // method (default entry)
     { 
          System.out.print("Hello World!"); 
     }
}
```

It is not that much different from C (which is an imperative language), the only difference being the class encapsulating wrapper.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

main() {                     // function (default entry)
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could have more opportunity to explain OOP concepts if you implemented something like this.

```java
public abstract class Greeting
{ 
     public abstract String getHelloWorldMessage();
}
```

```java
public class EnglishGreeting extends Greeting
{ 
     private final String HELLO_WORLD_MESSAGE = "Hello World!";

     public String getHelloWorldMessage() { 
          return HELLO_WORLD_MESSAGE;
     }
}
```

```java
public class SpanishGreeting extends Greeting
{ 
     private final String HELLO_WORLD_MESSAGE = "¡Hola Mundo!";

     public String getHelloWorldMessage() { 
          return HELLO_WORLD_MESSAGE;
     }
}
```

```java
public class Main
{ 
     public static void main(String[] args) { 
          Greeting englishGreeting = new EnglishGreeting();
          Greeting spanishGreeting = new SpanishGreeting();
          System.out.print(englishGreeting.getHelloWorldMessage());
          System.out.print(spanishGreeting.getHelloWorldMessage());
     }
}
```

Comment: This concept is known as polymorphism - specifically method overriding.

Answer (score -1):

The classic one:

Never use this:

```
class Greeting
{ 
 public static void main(String[] args)
 { 
      System.out.print("Hello World!");
 }
}
```

Always use this:

```
class Greeting
{ 
 public static void main(String[] args)
 { 
      new Greeting().hi();
 }

 private void hi(){
  System.out.print("Hello World!");
 }
}
```

this is simple answer :-) But, in your code you should use static context.